# how to increase the heap size for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-memory

in Eclipse workspace my application size is more than 200MB so every time it is prompting below dialog box

[image]

then i try to increase the heap size from eclipse.ini file

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20140116-2212
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

here when i give the xmx as 1024 eclipse is not even opening it is prompting the error dialog box as below
[image]

if i give less than this size it is again giving the same issue.

please any one tell me how to fix this issue.

Comment: The eclipse.ini is the correct place. 'Failed to create JVM' means your operating system is refusing to give the JVM that amount of memory. Try different values to see what the maximum you can get is.

Comment: thanks for your reply my o.s is windows7 4GB ram 64 bit. upto 512MB as maximum heap size it is accepting but it is not sufficient.

Comment: You are running a 32 bit Eclipse and Java, you will get more memory using 64 bit Eclipse and Java (you must upgrade both).

Comment: thanks you very much for your Answer. can you please tell me how to increase in 32 eclipse. but my java is 64 bit.

Comment: 32 bit Eclipse will not run on 64 bit Java so you must be using a 32 bit Java. You have to install a new Eclipse to get 64 bit.